# ':' character in JasperReports HTML output

Tags: encoding, jasper-reports

I am working with JasperReports with HTML as the export format. The problem is that from my Java class, I set the parameter with a String value containing the '`:`' character, when I click the button to produce the report, the field which contains the '`:`' character, change its position and showed somewhere else, if I remove the '`:`', it works fine.

Some inputs

1. My jrxml is UTF-8 encoded
2. I tried replacing '`:`' with '`\u003a`' still no luck
3. I tried replacing '`:`' with '`&#58;`' this gives me '`&amp;#58;`' but not '`:`'
4. The jrxml is something like this, here the 'leaveTime' has the value with a character ':' and because of that it does not display in the table but displayed somewhere else on the screen (with different x and y value).

```xml
<detail>
    <band height="15">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="600" y="0" width="120" height="15"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{supervisorName}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="532" y="0" width="65" height="15"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{leaveTime}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: "change its position and showed somewhere else" this part isn't clear. Include a bit of the .jrxml and of the HTML to make problem clearer.

Comment: Hi, it changes the position on the screen, x and y values that I have specified in the xml.   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="532" y="0" width="65" height="15"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{leaveTime}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>

Comment: @user1105221 Can you post the snippet of your jrxml file with parameter and elements that use it?

Comment: Hi, have added in the post. Thanks

Comment: Include some of the HTML to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is this: JasperReports is putting whatever value you have for $F{leaveTime} into the report. This could include characters that are not HTML-friendly. This is reasonable, since JR doesn't know if you will export to Excel or PDF or HTML or something else. Your idea of replacing '`:`' with '`\u003a`' is correct conceptually... but not quite right in its details. You need HTML escaping, not UTF-8 escaping.

I think in this specific case you need `&#58;`.

More generally you should use a library built for escaping HTML strings. I recommend using Apache Commons Lang. That way you could replace `$F{leaveTime}` with `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml($F{leaveTime})`.

Comment: Hi, this is not working either, it rendering with proper colon character but again, changing its position.